# Grid not reducing size after children collapse

Tags: wpf

This is the structure of the program:

```
- window
  - styles
    - togglebutton
    - textblock
  - grid
```

Each row in the grid will be a toggle button and when we click the togglebutton the textblock expands and when we click it again the textblock collapses.

The problem is when it expands, the window increases in size but when it collapses it won't reduce the size to the rows size. What to do for this? Can anyone help?

I tried setting the windows sizetocontent property to width and height and it is not the problem. I think there is something to do with the grid and not the window.

Comment: Your RowHeight = auto? If nothing helps you ll have to create a binding

Comment: binding for which control? row heights are auto.

Comment: I dint keep the grid in a dockpanel but the style which i apply for the rows that contains togglebutton and textblock are in a stackpanel. Will this suffice?

Comment: anyone got an answer for this one? just come across the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you were in the right way, using `SizeToContent` property of the window!

Try this code (declare the Converter and change references!):

C# `IValueConverter` for the visibility of the children

```
public sealed class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML code for your window

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TestWpf.Converters"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Title="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Row 1-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Orientation="Vertical">
        <ToggleButton Content="expand/collapse"
                      x:Name="Button1" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=Button1}"
                   Text="Sample Text 1" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!--Row 2-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                Orientation="Vertical">
        <ToggleButton Content="expand/collapse"
                      x:Name="Button2" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=Button2}"
                   Text="Sample Text 2" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!--Row 3-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                Orientation="Vertical">
        <ToggleButton Content="expand/collapse"
                      x:Name="Button3" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=Button3}"
                   Text="Sample Text 3" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have done as you told above and it is just the same.. No change.